# Making command-line programs with arguments

Tags: c++, command, cmd, creation

I discovered that it is possible to create command-line programs via C++.
I am a C++ rookie and I know only basic things, but still, I want to use it to create new command-line programs. 
Now, I have discovered this code:

```
//file name: getkey.exe
#include <conio.h>
int main(){
    if (kbhit())  return getche() | ('a' - 'A');
}
```

which surprisingly  simple, and it runs like this: *getkey* 
But it doesn't explain how to create a command with arguments (like: getkey /? or /K or /foo...)

How to create a command-line program with arguments? **<< Main question**

Comment: Step 1: [Get a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Step 2: Read through said book and do the exercises. Step 3: Read up on command line arguments and how you can get them via `int main(int argc, char**argv)`.

Comment: I think what you call "CMD commands" are more commonly known as "programs". Yes, C++ is a programming language and can be used to create programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

define the function `main` as taking these two arguments:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
```

`argc` will be populated with the *number* of arguments passed and `argv` will be an *array of those parameters*, as null-terminated character strings.  (C-style strings)

The program name itself will count as the first parameter, so `getkey /?` will set argc to `2`, `argv[0]` will be "`getkey`" and `argv[1]` will be "`/?`"

Answer (score 5):

You'd just want a different declaration of `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int ac, char* av[]) {
{
    std::cout << "command line arguments:\n";
    for (int i(1); i != ac; ++i)
        std::cout << i << "=" << av[i] << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To process command line arguments change:

```
int main()
```

to

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

`argc` is the number of command line arguments (the number of elements in `argv`).
`argv` is the command line arguments (where the first entry in `argv` is the name of program executable).